# Get a custom field price value for a custom post type in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, price

I am using the following code to use custom post type's custom field to use as a price field. So that I can add this field value in cart and make the payment.

Good news is that this custom post is successfully going into cart **but the problem is that price value is Wrong**.

Price should be $400 but it is displaying $51,376.

Here is the code:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
// Put your plugin code here

add_action('woocommerce_loaded' , function (){
    //Put your code here that needs any woocommerce class
    //You can also Instantiate your main plugin file here
    class WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT
    {

        /**
         * Method to read a product from the database.
         * @param WC_Product
         */

        public function read(&$product)
        {

            $product->set_defaults();

            if (!$product->get_id() || !($post_object = get_post($product->get_id())) || !in_array($post_object->post_type, array('refered_customer', 'product'))) { // change birds with your post type
                throw new Exception(__('Invalid product.', 'woocommerce'));
            }

            $id = $product->get_id();

            $product->set_props(array(
                'name' => $post_object->post_title,
                'slug' => $post_object->post_name,
                'date_created' => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp($post_object->post_date_gmt) : null,
                'date_modified' => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp($post_object->post_modified_gmt) : null,
                'status' => $post_object->post_status,
                'description' => $post_object->post_content,
                'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
                'parent_id' => $post_object->post_parent,
                'menu_order' => $post_object->menu_order,
                'reviews_allowed' => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
            ));

            $this->read_attributes($product);
            $this->read_downloads($product);
            $this->read_visibility($product);
            $this->read_product_data($product);
            $this->read_extra_data($product);
            $product->set_object_read(true);
        }

        /**
         * Get the product type based on product ID.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @param int $product_id
         * @return bool|string
         */
        public function get_product_type($product_id)
        {

            $post_type = get_post_type($product_id);
            if ('product_variation' === $post_type) {
                return 'variation';
            } elseif (in_array($post_type, array('refered_customer', 'product'))) { // change birds with your post type
                return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'woocommerce_data_stores' );

function woocommerce_data_stores ( $stores ) {

$stores['product'] = 'WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT';

return $stores;

}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_product_get_price( $invoice_price, $product ) {

if ($post->post->post_type === 'refered_customer') // change birds with your post type

    $invoice_price = get_post_meta($post->id, "invoice_price", true);

return $invoice_price;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - In your last hooked function to get the right price, you have some errors:

- `$post->post->post_type` **will not work** as the `$post` object **is not defined**.
- `$post->id` should be `$post->ID`, **but it will not work** as the `$post` object **is not defined**.

Instead you will use dedicated functions and methods: [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) and [`$product->get_id()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html).

So try this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Change birds with your post type
    if ( get_post_type( $product->get_id() ) === 'refered_customer' )
        $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), "invoice_price", true );

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

Comment: LoicTheAztec thank you very much for the right direction. But get_the_ID() function return cart page id not custom post type. Do you know why this happen and how can I get the custom post type id on cart page...

Comment: Yes, it is working now. For sure I will accept this answer. You deserve it. Thanks you very much for the helpful tips...

Comment: LoicTheAztec! one more thing... function get_post_type() returns "page". Can you help me how can get custom post type "refered_customer" on cart page.....

Comment: @Gurjit Updated again with `get_post_type( $product->get_id() )`… It should definitively work now.